# Difference between save() and pre-save and post-save

Tags: python, django

I'm a newbie in `Django` and I have the following questions, and I need your advice. The Django documentation is not enough for me as it is missing the examples

here we put `.save()` function: and don't know should I use pre/post

```
def update_total(self):
    self.total=self.cart.total+self.shipping_total
    self.save()
```

In the `postsave` function we didn't put `save()`

```
def postsave_order_total(sender,instance,created,*args,**kwargs):
    if  created:
        print("just order created ")
        instance.update_total()

post_save.connect(postsave_order_total,sender=orders)
```

and with m2m signal we put .save function, is it true and if it is why we didn't put `.save()` in `pre_save` or `post_save()`

```
def cal_total(sender,instance,action,*args,**kwargs):
    # print(action)
    if action=="post_add" or action=="post_remove" or action=="post_clear":
        prod_objs=instance.products.all()
        subtotal=0
        for prod in prod_objs:
            subtotal+=prod.price
        print(subtotal)
        total=subtotal+10
        instance.total=total
        instance.subtotal=subtotal
        instance.save()


m2m_changed.connect(cal_total, sender=cart.products.through)
```

In the m2m signal why I specified the action:

```
if action=="post_add" or action=="post_remove" or action=="post_clear"
```

Also in the update , I didn't use `save()` with it.

```
qs = orders.objects.filter(cart=instance.cart,active=instance.active).exclude(billing_profile=instance.billing_profile)
    if qs.exists():
        qs.update(active=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

`pre_save` is before the save of the model and `post_save` is after the save of the model.

This is where you process info before let's say to make sure if data is valid before saving or post_save after model is saved to attach a file.